# list[-1:] returns last value, but is not == last value?

Tags: python, list, indexing, slice

I'm still very new to coding, as in I've been coding for a few days. I'm trying to teach myself python by working on a small personal project. I've been playing around with list slicing, and something doesn't add up to me, which is impeding a function I'm trying to make.

By playing around in the shell (correct terminology?) I've deduced that:

```
    >>> list1 = "hello"
    >>> list2 = list(list1)
    >>> list2[-1:]
    >>> 'o'
    >>> list2[-1:] == 'o'
    >>> False
    >>> list2[0]
    >>> 'h'
    >>> list2[0] == 'h'
    >>> True
```

Why is this? At first I thought since maybe list2 was defined by another list, its last index would not be == to list1's because list1 could be redefined? But then I tried the first index and now I'm confused.

Comment: `list2[-1:] -> ['hello']`, no idea where you are getting `o` from. `list2[0][-1] -> o`. `list2[0]` is also `"hello"` not `h`.

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax. Drop the ":" after the -1.

Comment: @Lagerbaer The syntax is fine; the reported value of `list2[-1:]` as `'o'` is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch all the weird extra stuff that was going on with his indexing and initializing

Comment: @quesadyllan,  in place of creating input/output that looks like it came from a python shell, you should actually use the python shell. If you did you would not be asking this question.

Comment: lol I didn't just make this up, I copied it over exactly how it came out. I was just wondering if someone could explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you meant to show is

```
>>> list1 = 'hello'
>>> list1
'hello'
>>> list2 = list(list1)
>>> list2
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

In this case,

```
>>> list2[-1]
'o'
>>> list2[-1:]
['o']
```

As you can see, `list2[-1:]` returns a list, thus it's not equal to `'o'`.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Ignore the stuff below. In your example, list2 is a list that contains, as an element, the string "hello". That is different from being the string "hello".

---

List syntax in pythpm is `[from:to:stepsize]`.
If you omit any of these, the rest is implied with things that "make sense". For example,

`list2[:3] == 'hel'`
`list2[1:] == 'ello'`
`list2[::-1] == 'olleh'`
Finally, if you don't have any colons in there, you are accessing a SINGLE element.

`list2[0] == 'h'`
`list2[-1] == 'o'`

Comment: `list2[::-1] -> ['hello']`, you slice a list, you get a list.

Comment: Argh. I got thrown off by OPs weird initializing of the list where it just doesn't make sense

Comment: None of the question really makes sense.